# Send Image File Data to RESTful Service

Tags: javascript, c#, rest

On my site I have an `input` element of type `file` (using it for camera capture on mobile devices). I want to send the data from the image to the server. My problem is that I don't know the correct datatypes to use in this situation. I've tried using the `FileReader` API to get the data as a string and I always get a 413 (Request Too Large).

All I want to do is have the user take a picture, send this picture to the server (so it can process off and save the EXIF data) and have the server return the data. I know how to read the EXIF data on the server, I know how to capture the image on the client, but I can't seem to get how to send the captured image data to the service correctly.

Note: the server is C#.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "the server is c#"...that's pretty general. Is it asp.net web api?  A WCF service?  A generic handler?

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed regarding your C# webserver.

Hoever, in the example below, everywhere it says PHP-whatever, you have to know (or create) equivalent functionality in your C# webserver:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Also check out how to see html traffic in your browser when you run the above example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It might also be worth your time to know about jsbin and postimage to quickly try out examples:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tools-of-the-trade-jsbin--net-36843

http://postimage.org/about.php